# Calculate Available Height For Element To Occupy?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following three Iframes on a page.
the red Iframe contains 3 main elements of which the scrollable div is loaded dynamically.

I want to set the height of the scroll-able div when it loads to an amount so that it does not push the buttons out of users view.

I have to take into account the jQuery Tabs Height and the buttons height and the window/Iframe height then do `scrollableDivHeight = (windowHeight-jqueryTabsHeight-buttonsHeight).`

[image]

I understand this might be trivial to some but I am just beginning java-script and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code..

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(window).load(function(){ // Window load .. to ensure that images are loaded from header and footer part, then the body part is resized
            var winW = 630, winH = 460;
                if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) { 
                 //Internet Explorer (backward-compatibility mode):
                 winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
                 winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
                }
                if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' &&
                    document.documentElement &&
                    document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
                //Internet Explorer (standards mode, document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat'):
                 winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
                 winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
                }
                if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
                 // most other browsers – as well as IE9 (standards mode):
                 winW = window.innerWidth;
                 winH = window.innerHeight;
                }

            var headerHeight = $("#head").outerHeight(true); // include margin  
            var footerHeight = $("#foot").outerHeight(true); // include margin
            var extraBitForIe8 = 0; 
            if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version==8)
                extraBitForIe8= 4; // For ie 8, to avoid scroll bar
            var bodyHeight = winH - headerHeight - footerHeight - extraBitForIe8 
            $("#body").height(bodyHeight);
        })        
    </script>


    </head>
    <body  >
        <div id="head" style="background:red; margin:10px; padding:10px; color: white" >Header content goes here <br> Header content goes here <br> Header content goes here</div>
        <div id="body" style="background:black; color:white; margin:0 10px; padding:0 10px;"  >Body content goes here <br>Body content goes here  <br> Body content goes here </div>
        <div id="foot"  style="background:yellow; margin:10px; padding:10px;" >Footer content goes here <br> Footer content goes here <br> Footer content goes here</div> 
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Detecting the available height of the browser window might be tricky (i.e. browser-dependent). Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow.
You will probably also need to set fixed height for the buttons and tabs.